# Deploying an application with Capistrano after server was setup with Chef

Tags: capistrano, chef-infra

I have an application server that was setup using a Chef cookbook. The recipe uses the opscode [application](https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks/application) cookbook to do an initial deploy of the app code from a private GitHub repo. Now I want to add Capistrano to the mix to handle future code deploys. Here I run into trouble. The application cookbook uses the same folder structure as Capistrano, so I figured they were meant to work with eachother, but I am having a hard time getting them to play nice.

Can anyone shed some light on what my Capistrano recipe might look like to handle something like this. Since I am using a private repo, and using the built in ssh-wrapper capabilities of the application cookbook, I'm pretty sure I need to configure Capistrano to work the same way.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand: why would you want to do that? Are you discontinuing use of Chef on that node? or is the application cookbook lacking functionality that you have in Capistrano?

Comment: No, the application cookbook works great, I just find it a bit overkill that every time I want to do a code push, I have to re-run the chef client. I have heard mixed opinions on this, but for me I feel I'm leaning towards wanting to have a desperate script for code deploys, after Chef sets up the box and does the initial deploy. I'd there a way to get the two working synergistically?

Comment: That makes sense. FWIW, we run chef-client periodically, and then if there's an "urgent" need to push *right now* we would run it manually, maybe with `chef-client -o "recipe[myapp]" to make it quicker. And by manually I mean with knife ssh. I've never tried mixing it with Capistrano so unfortunately I can't really help.

Comment: Hmm...I was unaware that you could do a chef-client run and have it only run a specific recipe. That might just work.

Comment: Yeah, give it a try. I've turned it into a proper answer so you can accept it if it turns out to be a solution ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option that may work for you is to do a chef-client run with just the recipe that deploys your application:

```
chef-client -o "recipe[myapp]"
```